# Error:XPC connection interrupted

Tags: iphone, swift

I am scheduling notification by running the loop in an array.Notification is working fine.But my application is crashing with this error.I know that the OS stops working and os gets rebooted but if i dont call this scheduleNotification function then everything works fine so i know that the error is generation because of this function when i pops to other screen and comes back again my app gets crashg but i dont know why?? please help me out.

```
 func scheduleNotification() {
    if dictInfo.object(forKey: "name") !as AnyObject as ? String == "zzz" {

    } else {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var calendarComponents = DateComponents()
        let strDay = (dictInfo["dd"
            as NSString] !as AnyObject).doubleValue
        let strMonth = (dictInfo["mm"
                as NSString]) !

        let dayy = strDay
        let monthh = strMonth

        calendarComponents.hour = 11
        calendarComponents.minute = 04
        calendarComponents.day = Int(dayy!) - 2
        print(calendarComponents.day)

        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MM" // if you need 3 letter month just use "LLL"
        let datee1 = df.date(from: String(describing: monthh))
        print(datee1)
        let monthh11 = (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).component(.month, from: datee1!)
        print(monthh11) // 5

        //calendarComponents.year = Int(yearr!)
        calendarComponents.month = Int(monthh11)

        let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: calendarComponents.month, day: calendarComponents.day, hour: calendarComponents.hour, minute: calendarComponents.minute)

        if# available(iOS 10.0, * ) {
            let strName: String = String(describing: dictInfo["name"] !)

            let str2: String! = "Today is \(strName)\'s Birthday!"

            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Alert Me!"
            content.body = str2
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

            content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"
            content.userInfo = ((dictInfo as Any) as ? [AnyHashable: Any]) !
            print(content.userInfo.count)


            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: strName, content: content, trigger: trigger)

            // UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {
                (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    MBProgressHUD.hide(
        for: self.view, animated: true)
    tableVieww.isHidden = false
        //self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true

}
```

Comment: Seems like nobody is interested in helping anyone who needs it :(

Comment: Could you paste the error / stack trace that you get from the crash? In general you are not getting much attention because this question is really just "help me debug my code", which is not what stackoverflow is really about. You've got a whole load of code there, and I can spot some potential issues, but I have no idea which bit of it is where the crash is. [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59991/what-are-the-top-issues-when-it-comes-to-low-quality-questions) is a good guide for writing questions. Posting only the relevant code that reproduces the issue is also very important.

Comment: 2016-11-18 15:19:14.159452 AlertME![5727:2344565] XPC connection interrupted
2016-11-18 15:19:14.160020 AlertME![5727:2344144] [Common] Terminating since there is no system app.

Comment: Its crashing with this error when i try to schedule around 20 to 30 notifications continously one after another. And im sure the problem is that the schedulenotification function does not excute properly because i try to add request quickly one after one.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with the current amount of information. You say it's crashing, but you have no stack trace. Have you tried setting break points and stepping through the code? You need to get further into debugging the problem yourself and get to the stage where you can say "this exact thing is not working, and I don't understand why - I will post on stack overflow". Ravi Shankar provides a [good basic intro](http://rshankar.com/debugging-swift-app-in-xcode/) to debugging swift apps.